# wp_kses enable all attributes of specific tags

Tags: php, wordpress, escaping

I'm using wp_kses to render a string containing an img tag, but it has some dynamic attributes also, I know I can define tag with attributes like this

```
                       echo wp_kses( $img_tag_string, array(
                            'img' => array(
                                'src' => array(),
                                'class' => array(),
                                'alt' => array(),
                                'title' => array(),
                            ),
                        ) );
```

But there are some other attributes also like width, height. Is there any way I can define just img tag and it can contain any attributes?

Comment: It does not work like that, it is used to white-list the tags your supply, so you should add everything you want to allow.

Comment: Any alternate to that?